How to automate the process of getting on-demand coretime?
I'm testing on-demand coretime on Zombienet.
This blog is very helpful to get the cores in Zombienet: https://polkadot-public.notion.site/Agile-Coretime-FAQ-c930796e8c884011adb1fa24ef22f77c
In On-demand coretime, whenever we need a core then everytime we need to execute this extrisincs onDemandAssignmentProvider from relay chain manually.
Can we get the on-demand core automatically?
Is this concept already exists? If not how we can approach to this functionality?
For ex: let's say at 5PM, Everyday I need a on-demand core so what can be the automatic mechanism in which I can get the one coretime at 5PM everyday without any manual intervention?
